# Bundle Prerequisites along with WPF Client Once deployed in Azure Virtual Machine IIS

Tags: azure, clickonce

We have developed a WPF application and published it as Click Once in local development machine. After testing the application we edited the .application file and deployed it in the Virtual machine IIS. Now the issue is with bundling the prerequisites with for the click once. When we publish local it has created a setup.exe file. But when we upload the published component in the windows azure machine and click install from the client machine it gives an error as prerequisites file not found, showing the local development machine details. How to sort out this issue. We need to include .NET Framework 4.0., SQL server compact and Crystal report prerequisites. how to include redistributable for these in to prerequisites bundle.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you edited the .application file (deployment manifest) using mageUI or mage, and re-signed the deployment before deploying the files. 
The setup.exe file has the URL for the deployment and info about the prerequisites in it. What you might want to do is publish the deployment to a local folder (publishing file location), but set the installation URL for what it will be from the VM, THEN take it and copy it over there. This will ensure that setup.exe has the right URL.

Also note that for .NET 4, you probably have to edit the package xml and enable SAMESITE. I don't have the instructions for .NET 4, but they should be similar, if not identical, to the instructions for .NET 3.5. Check out [this document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/2/8/A2807F78-C861-4B66-9B31-9205C3F22252/VS2008SP1Readme.htm) (search for "samesite").